# LINQPad - C# vs VB Issue

Tags: c#, vb.net, entity-framework, linq, linqpad

I'm having a strange issue that I feel like is more than likely something dumb on my part, but my initial google searching doesn't seem to yield me any results.

In short, I work for a company still writing in VB, and I am currently doing the "LINQPad challenge", writing all of my ad-hoc queries in LINQ instead of using SQL Server Management Studio. That said, because I prefer to practice in C# for my inevitable move to that language, I want to do my querying in C#.

Below are two statements which I am running in LINQPad - the VB one fires fine and returns the data, but the C# one fires and does nothing (no errors, just doesn't do anything..). Is there something wrong in my C# code? It wouldn't surprise me as I'm rusty with C# due to working in VB every day.

Below are the two queries, which I believe are equivalent.. They are firing against our Entity Framework, which was generated in Visual Studio Database first. Again, the VB one returns the tskID column, while the C# one doesn't seem to do anything.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**VB LINQ:**

```
TblTasks.Join(
                TblEmployeeTimePunches, 
                Function(tsks) tsks.tskID, 
                Function(etps) etps.etpTask_tskID, 
                Function(tsks,etps) New With { tsks, etps }) _
    .Select(Function(s) s.tsks.TskID)
```

**C# LINQ:**

```
TblTasks
    .Join(
            TblEmployeeTimePunches, 
            tsks => tsks.TskID, 
            etps => etps.EtpTask_tskID, 
            (tsks, etps) => new {
                                    tsks,
                                    etps
                                }
         ).Select(
                    s => s.tsks.TskID
                  );
```

Comment: The case (upper/lower) are different in the vb.net and c3.  Why?

Comment: I had typed out the VB one first (which doesn't enforce case-sensitivity), and when converting it to C#, case sensitivity kicked in and I corrected it. That said, just to verify that isn't causing my problem I went ahead and modified the VB query to match the case and I do get the same result (i.e. C# version still not doing anything).

Comment: I don't think the issue is with the code posted.  I would make sure that TblTasks contain same data in both cases.

Comment: I wonder if the semi-colon at the end of your C# expression causes LINQPad's `Dump` method to not be called automatically? what happens if you change the `;` to `.Dump()`?

Comment: That was it @Keith Hall! I tried changing it to .Dump() and i get the results. I also get results if I changed it to C# Expression. Not sure how I didn't end up trying that... but either way, that worked - Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of query you've chosen under "Language" matters.  C# Statements require .Dump() calls for output.  C# Expressions automatically show their output.  My guess is that you may have these mixed up.

Comment: Yup, that was the issue, I knew it'd be something dumb I was overlooking. Thanks for the help!